# How can I store perforce P4V password?

Tags: perforce

I have to use this software and I need to store password, because it disconnects regularly. How can I do that, there is no checkbox to save password.

Thanx a lot!

Comment: Ugly software? Seems it is a software usage question

Comment: Ok, now it politically-correct.

Comment: P4V should automatically keep you logged in for 12 hours; you may have hit a login bug that was in an older version of V. Make sure you have the latest release.

Comment: I want to be logged int forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are an administrator (or can convince your admin to do this), you can create a group, put yourself in it, then edit the group permissions to prevent your session from ever timing out.

In P4V group management is done via Tools->Administration->Permissions tab->Groups tab

[image]

Set the "Duration before login session times out" to "unlimited".

You can also do it from the command line:

```
p4 group <group name>
```

When the group specification opens in a text editor, set the `PasswordTimeout:` property to `unlimited`.