# Save password for P4 visual client

Tags: perforce

I am using the below version of p4 visual client. Everytime, I launch the client it prompts me for a password. Is there a way that I can set the password (encrytped) as an env variable so that it doesn't prompt me for a password . I am using Windows 7 operating system.

**Version::** Rev. Perforce Visual Client/NTX64/2014.3/1007540

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224301/how-can-i-store-perforce-p4v-password

Answer (score 4):

If your server's security level is 2 or lower, you can store your password in the 'P4PASSWD' environment variable, but it is not encrypted.

More information about server security levels, passwords and tickets is available here:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/chapter.superuser.html#DB5-49899

Currently P4V does not have a mechanism to store your password within the application, but you may wish to consider submitting your suggesting to P4IdeaX:

http://www.p4ideax.com

Hope this helps,
Jen!

Comment: Thanks Jen. I will take a look at the documentation.